Can we conclude that an infinite bounded exponent periodic locally nilpotent group $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups?
When $G$ is a finite nilpotent group, we know that $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. Now, assume that $G$ is an infinite locally nilpotent group. Also, consider that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $x^n=1$, for any $x\in G$.  ($G$ is a bounded exponent periodic group. ) Can we conclude that  $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups? When $p$ range over all prime divisors of $n$.

Free Burnside groups seem to be related.   This may be difficult.   I doubt a posting on math overflow would be out of the question.

For each prime $p$ dividing $n$ the $p$-elements form a subgroup which is therefore the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup, and Sylow $p$-subgroups satisfy the standard conditions for being a direct product, so yes.

Theorem 12.1.1 of "A Course in the Theory of Groups" by D.J.S. Robinson states:
Let $G$ be a locally nilpotent group. Then the elements of finite order in $G$ form a fully invariant subgroup $T$ (the torsion subgroup of $G$) such that $G/T$ is torsion-free and $T$ is a direct product of $p$-groups.
